# Can I Use Order by to sort Stored Procedure results?

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures

Simply, I have this SQL statment:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'tasklist'
```

can we order or filter the results by using `order by` or `where`?

Thanks,

Comment: You could add these as parameters to the sp: http://4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/010704-1.shtml

Comment: No it's not Duplicated, I want tSQL Code not in DotNet platform.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You need to output the results into a temporary table first. This should show you how to do it

[Insert results of a stored procedure into a temporary table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/653714/how-to-select-into-temp-table-from-stored-procedure)

Answer (score 23):

I checked jamietre link, and this is the complete answer:

```
Create table  #MyTempTable
(output varchar(max))

INSERT INTO #MyTempTable
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'tasklist' 

select * from #MyTempTable where output like 'ie%' order by output
```

Thanks for all...

Answer (score 3):

not directly.  You can insert exec into a temp table or table variable and then sort that though

Answer (score 2):

When running the above query multiple times, you might run into this error: `There is already an object named '#MyTempTable' in the database.`

To mitigate this you can use a `DROP IF EXISTS` statement as follows before creating the `temp table`.

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb..#MyTempTable') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN
DROP TABLE #MyTempTable
END
CREATE TABLE #MyTempTable
(OUTPUT VARCHAR(max))

INSERT INTO #MyTempTable
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'tasklist' 

SELECT * FROM #MyTempTable WHERE OUTPUT like 'ie%' ORDER BY OUTPUT
```